# Getting Error : NX Failed to create directory: /app/node_modules/.cache/nx while creating Docker Image

Tags: docker, next.js, monorepo, nrwl-nx

I was trying to dockerize the monorepo with `NX`, `NEXTJS` and "NESTJS app, Tried the below

**Dockerfile.frontend** -

```
# Install deps and build the source code only when needed
FROM node:lts-alpine AS builder
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile

COPY . .

# RUN yarn nx run frontend:build:production --skip-nx-cache
RUN yarn nx run frontend:build:production -skip-nx-cache

# Production image, copy all the files and run next
FROM node:lts-alpine AS runner
WORKDIR /app

ENV NODE_ENV production

RUN addgroup -g 1001 -S nodejs
RUN adduser -S nextjs -u 1001

COPY --from=builder /app/dist/apps/frontend/package.json ./
RUN yarn install --ignore-scripts

# You only need to copy next.config.js if you are NOT using the default configuration
# COPY --from=builder /app/dist/apps/withlib/next.config.js ./
# COPY --from=builder /app/dist/apps/withlib/public ./public
COPY --from=builder /app/dist/apps/frontend/ ./

# Automatically leverage output traces to reduce image size
# https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/output-file-tracing
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/dist/apps/frontend/.next ./.next

USER nextjs
EXPOSE 7000

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

But I am unable to run the `npm start` which is mentioned in the `package.json` as -

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "nx serve",
    "build": "nx build",
    "test": "nx test"
  },
```

Getting the Error - After the Container and Network creation as -  ***>  NX   Failed to create directory: /app/node_modules/.cache/nx*** while running `nx serve`.

Can someone please suggest me where I am performing wrong operation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I have achieved with **NEXTJS** App `Dockerfile` -

```
FROM node:lts-alpine AS base
RUN apk update
RUN apk add libc6-compat
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN yarn install
FROM node:18.16.0-slim AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=base /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . .
RUN yarn run nx build frontend
# Production image, copy all the files and run next
FROM node:18.16.0-slim AS runner
WORKDIR /app
ENV NODE_ENV production
# Uncomment the following line in case you want to disable telemetry during runtime.
# ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1
# RUN addgroup --system --gid 1001 nodejs
# RUN adduser --system --uid 1001 nextjs
# You only need to copy next.config.js if you are NOT using the default configuration
# COPY --from=builder /app/next.config.js ./
COPY --from=builder /app/dist/apps/frontend .
COPY --from=builder /app/.env ./.env
RUN npm --omit=dev -f install && \
    npm install sharp --save && \
    npx next telemetry disable
# Automatically leverage output traces to reduce image size
# https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/output-file-tracing
# COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/standalone ./
# COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/static ./.next/static
# USER nextjs
EXPOSE 3000
# Install PM2 globally
RUN npm install pm2 -g

# Use PM2 to start the application
CMD pm2-runtime npm -- start
```

Make sure that you have enabled the Generating the `package.json` inside the

> apps > your frontend project

Like below -

```
"generatePackageJson": true,
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to run this in Kubernetes or an environment that makes the docker file system read only? Likely that is the issue. To get around it (if you are running in kubernetes) create a volume / mount at the nx cache location. This should get it running

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information provided in this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1088272/inotify-add-watch-failed-no-space-left-on-device),
it seems that the error "inotify_add_watch failed: No space left on device" is related to running out of inotify watches.